# How to find nodes entirely between two specified nodes

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

In a XML document such as the following:

```
<root>
  <fish value="Start"/>
  <pointlessContainer>
    <anotherNode value="Pick me!"/>
    <anotherNode value="Pick me too!"/>
    <fish value="End"/>
  </pointlessContainer>
</root>
```

How can I use the wonder of LINQ to XML to find any nodes *completely* contained by the `fish` nodes? Note that in this example, I have deliberately placed the `fish` nodes at different levels in the document, as I anticipate this scenario will occur in the wild.

Obviously, in this example, I would be looking to get the two `anotherNode` nodes, but not the `pointlessContainer` node.

NB: the two 'delimiting' nodes may have the same type (e.g. `fish`) as other non-delimiting nodes in the document, but they would have unique attributes and therefore be easy to identify.

Comment: Might there be selected nodes which are *higher* in the tree than the "start" node?

Comment: Oh, you mean if the start and end nodes are on different branches kind of thing? I hadn't thought of that. I suppose technically it may be possible. tbh I don't know enough about this flavour of XML (WordML) to be sure.

Comment: I consider it highly unlikely, although nothing would surprise me about MS Office formats.

Answer (score 0):

For your sample, the following should do

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"..\..\XMLFile2.xml");
        XElement start = doc.Descendants("fish").First(f => f.Attribute("value").Value == "Start");
        XElement end = doc.Descendants("fish").First(f => f.Attribute("value").Value == "End");
        foreach (XElement el in 
            doc
            .Descendants()
            .Where(d => 
                XNode.CompareDocumentOrder(d, end) == -1 
                && XNode.CompareDocumentOrder(d, start) == 1 
                && !end.Ancestors().Contains(d)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(el);
        }
```

But I haven't tested or thoroughly pondered whether it works for other cases. Maybe you can check for some of your sample data and report back whether it works.

Comment: With something as complicated as this, I'm going for some serious unit testing, so I'll let you know if it passes them when I've written them!

Comment: Hmm. I can see what your code is doing. And thanks, it would have taken me hours to find methods like XNode.CompareDocumentOrder(). Thanks a bunch!